# another version of log-sine integral...rather tough.

Tags: integration

I ran across an integral with $\ln(\sin(x))$, and have not been able to make much headway.

Perhaps there is no closed form, but I thought I would post it to see if anyone has some clever ideas.

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\sqrt{\tan(x)}\cdot \ln(\sin(x))dx$

I tried various subs, but they did not yield anything manageable. At first glance, it looks like the classic Beta integral is in there somewhere.  How to deal with that $\sqrt{\tan(x)}$ poses the challenge.

Does anyone have ideas on a way to tackle this one?.

Comment: Maple doesn't do anything to this as an antiderivative. So its "likely" there's no simple closed form antiderivative. I also put it into maple including the limits, and again no answer; to me this means that it *might* be doable using contour integration or the like, but would be difficult (maple seems to know a lot of contour type definite integrals).

Comment: Thank you. I, too, ran it through Maple and it gave a numerical solution of $-.2708685659...$   I read a solution was supposed to be $\frac{-\pi \sqrt{2}}{48}\left({\pi}^{2}+12\pi \ln(2)+24\ln^{2}(2)\right)$.  But this does not check out numerically with what Maple gives, so I assume it is incorrect.

Comment: The Answer is  $$I=-\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{8}(3ln^{2}2+2{\pi}ln{2}-4G-\frac{\pi^2}{6})$$

Comment: Thanks for the closed form. Sorry for not being around. I recently had surgery. Anyway, I had forgotten all about this, but it looks like a fun and challenging integral.  How did you start this one?. I would love to see some of your ideas.